# Number field attached to a finite group.

Tags: number-theory, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group. I know that the set of irreducible representations of $G$ over the complex numbers (up to isomorphism) is finite.

Let us fix our attention on some irreducible representation of $G$ over $\Bbb{C}$ 
$$\rho: G \longrightarrow GL_n(\Bbb{C})$$
My intuition tells me that there exists some finite extension $K \supset \Bbb{Q}$, and some irreducible representation
$$\sigma:G \longrightarrow GL_n(K)$$
such that $\rho = i \circ \sigma$, where $i: GL_n(K) \longrightarrow GL_n(\Bbb{C})$ is the inclusion (every matrix with entries in $K$ has entries also in $\Bbb{C}$).

For example, if $G=C_2$ is the group with two elements, we can think the two irreducible representations of $C_2$ as $\sigma_1, \sigma_2 : C_2 \longrightarrow GL_1(\Bbb{Q})$, so $K=\Bbb{Q}$.

However I don't know if this is true for any finite group  (but I strongly believe that this is true, maybe you can give me some reference).

My question is: given $G$ a finite group, can we find some number field $K$, such that all irreducible representations of $G$ over the complex numbers can be thought as irreducible representations over $K$ (i.e. all involved matrices actually have entries in $K$)? Can we find a minimal such number field?

Comment: I came across this, and think it's relevant to your question

http://mathoverflow.net/questions/847/is-any-representation-of-a-finite-group-defined-over-the-algebraic-integers

Comment: Try to look up splitting field of a group.

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly true in the way that you state it; you could take an irreducible representation

$$\rho : G \to GL_n(K)$$

for some number field $K \subseteq \mathbb C$ and then conjugate it by some element $A$ of $GL_n(\mathbb C)$ with transcendental entries, to obtain a representation

$$A\rho A^{-1} : G \to GL_n(\mathbb C)$$

and there is no longer any reason why the entries of $A\rho(g)A^{-1}$ should be algebraic numbers, in general.

If you relax your condition of "equality" to "isomorphism", then it is true; every irreducible representation $G \to GL_n(\mathbb C)$ is isomorphic over $\mathbb C$ to a representation of the form $G \to GL_n(K) \to GL_n(\mathbb C)$.

Comment: Thanks. Actually this was in my mind, but I didn't wrote it.